# how can delete book from ibooks completely?

Tags: macos, ibook

I have a problem with iBooks that I download a book from iBook but I cant remove a totally the source of this book.

### how can solve this problem?

I edit this text because I didn't write about the device to delete from.

my device is MacBook Pro and I like to delete source of a file in types .epub from my iBooks but I cant do this and after removing the file from iBooks the book it's there and I just can hide it!

Comment: I find your question confusing. Could you include more information such as what you mean by totally remove, what device you are using, and how you obtained the book (iBooks or as a pdf from the internet)?

Comment: What are you trying to ask? I can't quite tell - what do you mean by (totally) removing the source? What device are you using? Where did you get the book from - did you get it from the store or did you download the eBook off the internet (.epub, .pdf...)?

Comment: Please improve the format of the question can be a little more elaborate!

Answer (score 2):

### To delete a book from iBooks on iOS

1. Click the select button in the top right of your screen
2. Select the book you want to delete
3. Click the delete button in the top left of your screen
4. Click delete everywhere to delete he book from all your devices (if applicable) or press remove download to remove it from just your current device.